# segues: what happens to the controller instance that calls the seque?

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uistoryboard

I didn't trust segues much at first (because of crashes if they were not set up correctly and because it wasn't clear to me what was going on under the hood) but I find I am using them more. I still don't exactly "get" what is going on though.

I have a segue between ViewController A and ViewController B with no UINavigationController involved. It does a FlipHorizontal transition, which I like.

When A initiates the segue, what happens to the A instance? I put a log statement in A's `viewDidUnload` method and it doesn't get called. So is A still lurking around? I'd like to be able to segue back to that same instance of A with all it's vars intact but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

As a test, I embedded A in a Nav Controller and tried both a segue and a push to B - and wasn't able to get back to my instance of A. What am I screwing up here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the difference between the view and the controller.  The calling controller is still around, and so is it's view.  However, any VIEW that is not on screen can be unloaded by the system.  That's when viewDidUnload will get called.

Basically, a controller, like every other object, lives until all references to it are gone.  In addition, anything the controller owns is still alive as well.  However, while it is still alive, it can get two important messages, which tell it "Get rid of anything you don't need or can rebuild."

One of them is viewDidUnload.  The other is didReceiveMemoryWarning.

So, yes, if you have a stack 100 view controllers deep within your NavController, then all 100 view controllers are still around... though some of their views may not be.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there any valid design pattern to pass the calling controller (A) to the destination controller (B) so the calling controller (A) can be set as the destination controller when returning from the segue initiated by B? Probably not but thought I would ask

Comment: Sorry, I got lost in that question somewhere.  What I think you are describing is handled by delegation or notification.  Before A calls B, he will do something like b.delegate = self, and when B is done, he will just notify the delegate the he's done.  A's delegate handler will the dismiss the controller.  If you use a navigation controller, it will automatically handle the pushing/popping for you.